# dbms_random.value works fine with code below except need to change date by assigned field

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracleforms

Dear I have this code which is work fine it generate random time which is generated till the last record found I have 2 fields where is :C field have date with different I can generate random time but in the same date how to assign :C field dates in that it take date from :C field and put into with this generated time

```
    
    START_DATE DATE := TO_DATE('01.01.2021 07:45', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi');
Begin

    FIRST_RECORD;
    LOOP
:a :=   START_DATE + round(dbms_random.value (1, 15))/ (24 * 60);
IF :system.last_record = 'FALSE'   
    THEN
       NEXT_RECORD;
    ELSE
       EXIT;
       END IF;
END LOOP;
End;
--it gives me data like this 
01.01.2021 07:59
01.01.2021 07:59
01.01.2021 07:57
01.01.2021 07:53
01.01.2021 07:47
01.01.2021 07:59
01.01.2021 07:54
01.01.2021 07:47
01.01.2021 07:57
01.01.2021 07:46
01.01.2021 07:47
```

I have :c field of date on forms which is tabular I want that it just pic date from :c and take time from this code like this

```
01.01.2021 07:59
02.01.2021 07:57
03.01.2021 07:53
04.01.2021 07:47
05.01.2021 07:59
```

Comment: @littlefoot please help me

Comment: As  a side note : replace the current local variable declaration with `START_DATE TIMESTAMP := timestamp'2021-01-01 07:45:00';`.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan dear its not working I replaced `START_DATE TIMESTAMP := timestamp('2021-01-01 07:45:00');` but not working and i don'nt want to give date Pre mentioned I want it take date from :C and time must be random between 07:45 to 08:00

Comment: i also tried without parentheses but no success than i put parentheses

Comment: well, I've meant [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4cce062014f31217032562f1cbf86086), but perhaps it might not work within the Forms which mşght have some restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, why don't you put that value into the `C` field in the same procedure, at once?

```
...

:a := START_DATE + round(dbms_random.value (1, 15))/ (24 * 60);

:c := trunc(:c)  + round(dbms_random.value (1, 15))/ (24 * 60);     --> this

...
```

Comment: Yes its working but how can i give it to time range like i want to make random it from 07:45am to 08:00am but it start from 12:00am

Comment: is it possible that I can set field property HH:MM AM and want to put initial values as 07:45 AM I set field as time but never takes in Now i am trying that i just take time in field and make it shuffle it and take date seprately

Comment: I'd rather NOT separate date and time values. In Oracle, there's the DATE datatype and it contains both date and time; there's no separate "TIME" datatype. If you split them, you can expect difficulties because "time" itself might default date to "today's date", which might not be what you wanted. Therefore, you'd have to include a set of controls on those fields, maybe record, maybe block ... depends. Basically, splitting date and time means quite a lot of more work for you. I wouldn't do it, if I were you & if possible.

Comment: I did this but in awkward manners i generate dates from 1 to 31 for jan and then  one date column with a fixed date generate mean 01-01-2021 with time format and after that applied agt all data which are shown in reports showed only time and calculated time which i need both are shown what i need :) :) I know this is not a way to do work but need in urgent then did this after that will find any solution Cheers @littlefoot you are so helping person or org i don't know but simply u are awesome thanks for every thing.